# Swiftui foreach inside parameter

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

how to foreach inside the view parameter

this is my code

```
  CarouselView(itemHeight: 124, views: [
                                SliderItemView(),
                                SliderItemView(),
                                SliderItemView(),
                ])
```

i want to iterate and show the SliderItemView with looping

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` cannot create an array.  If you want to create an array of those views one way to do it would be `[0..<3].map { _ in SliderItemView() }`

Comment: the result still show only one SliderItemView()

Comment: How are you working with the views inside of `CarouselfView`?  You need to show more of your code.

Comment: @ScottThompson: Why not? `ForEach` could be used for repeating a View! no issue there. In that case would no need to array of view, just a content that processed by ForEach.

Comment: `ForEach` can certainly be used to create multiple views.  But a `ForEach` is a **struct** it is not an **Array**.  That is precisely what I said.  The original poster was asking about creating multiple views using `ForEach` and demonstrated passing those views in an `Array`.  You cannot do that with `ForEach`.

Comment: I know it from beginning, but you help him to go in wrong way, or i would say you gave the right answer or wrong way. I also mentioned that the OP probably do not need or should not use an Array of View.

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 way for solving your issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        CustomViewV1(content: {

            ForEach(0...2, id:\.self) { _ in Text("Hello, World!").foregroundColor(Color.blue) }

        })

        CustomViewV2(repeating: 3, content: { Text("Hello, World!").foregroundColor(Color.red) })
        
    }
    
}



struct CustomViewV1<Content: View>: View {
    
   @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return content()
        
    }
    
}

struct CustomViewV2<Content: View>: View {
    
    let repeating: Int
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {

        if (repeating >= 1) {
            
            ForEach(1...repeating, id:\.self) { _ in
                
                content()
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

### result:

[image]